# How to place text after symbol in auto.key (lattice)?

Tags: r, plot, lattice

When using `auto.key` in `lattice`, can I swap the default positions of symbols and text? That is, I'd like the text in the legend to be on the right side with respect to the symbols. I know this is easy to do with `key`, but separately linking colours with groups for each plot isn't only tedious, but also very error-prone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you can't get `auto.key` to do this for you. Here is why:

- `auto.key` works by passing a list of arguments along to `simpleKey()`. From `?xyplot`:

  > auto.key: A logical, or a list containing components to be used as
  >             arguments to 'simpleKey'.
- `simpleKey()` in turn constructs a list (eventually passed on to `draw.key()`) in which **the text element always comes first**. Here are the key lines of `simpleKey()`:

  ```
  ans <- list(text = list(lab = text), col = col, cex = cex, 
      alpha = alpha, font = font, fontface = fontface, fontfamily = fontfamily, 
      ...)
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It's a shame that because of such a simple issue one has to do all the other stuff manually. The reason I'm upset about it is that just yesterday I created a legend with `key` by passing `points` (with custom colours) and `text`, and then  the mapping of the grouping variable to the colours changed somehow, and the legend became wrong. Is there a way to avoid such problems by getting the mapping of text and symbols automatically for the legend without using `auto.key`?

Comment: @AnjaM -- There are ways to get that info, but it's a bit of a maze (to me), and I won't be able to help right now. You could always work on it a bit, and then ask another SO question with a reproducible example of what you've tried and how you'd like it to work. Best of luck.